# Systemd script not running on shutdown

Tags: bash, 20.04, shutdown, systemd

I've been chasing my tail on this without success and I can't find why my script doesn't run on shutdown...

Running Ubuntu 20.04 (Desktop).

I created a /usr/local/sbin/run_on_shutdown.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
REBOOT=$( systemctl list-jobs | egrep -q 'reboot.target.*start' && echo "rebooting" || echo "not_rebooting" )
if [ $REBOOT = "not_rebooting" ]; then
########################################################################
# Put Bash commands here to be executed on shutdown but not on reboot. #
# For example, backup home directories to an external USB HDD. #
########################################################################

curl --silent --show-error -X POST https://example.com/trigger_something/abcdefkey
fi
```

I've `chmod +x /usr/local/sbin/run_on_shutdown.sh`

And created a systemd service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run run_on_shutdown.sh at shutdown
DefaultDependencies=no
Requires=network.target network-online.target
Before=network-online.target shutdown.target halt.target

# If your script requires any mounted directories, add them below:
# RequiresMountsFor=/home

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/run_on_shutdown.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target halt.target shutdown.target
```

Set permissions with `chmod 644 /etc/systemd/system/run_on_shutdown.service`

Reloaded the daemon: `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

And enabled it with: `sudo systemctl enable run_on_shutdown.service`

But... it doesn't run on shutdown... but runs with `sudo systemctl enable run_on_shutdown.service --now`

I can't find any evidence of it being called on shutdown anywhere so...

Can somebody help me or point me in the right direction please?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm uncertain, but I think you are missing `Conflicts=shutdown.target` and `RemainAfterExit=yes`.  This will keep your service active and stop your service when shutdown.target starts (ExecStart becomes ExecStop instead).

Comment: don't think Require= is necessary either.

Comment: Thanks, editing and testing right now, I'll post the results later!

Comment: Added 'Conflicts=shutdown.target' and 'RemainAfterExit=yes', comented out 'Requires=network.target network-online.target' but no dice.
Is there any way I can "see" what is the shutdown process running or error messages?

Comment: have you seen [How to run a script with systemd right before shutdown?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/479048/380915) (especially the last part) think it may be a better solution than a .service.

Comment: I've put the run_on_shutdown.sh on /usr/lib/systemd/system-shutdown but nothing happened also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will create the file shutdown.log in /opt/tmp on `shutdown.target` but not on `reboot.target`

```
[Unit]
Description=My Shutdown Service
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target
Conflicts=reboot.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash \
    -c 'mkdir -p /opt/tmp && \
        echo shutdown | ts >> $_/shutdown.log'
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=shutdown.target
```

Comment: Remember to `systemctl daemon-reload`, `systemctl enable my-shutdown.service`

Comment: This did it! I just replaced 'mkdir -p /opt/tmp && echo shutdown | ts >> $_/shutdown.log' with my curl command!
Thank you both very much for the help!

Comment: If you intend to use the network, you may need to add dependencies to the *network.target* (...and you should not need this REBOOT and if statement).

Comment: Slightly older Ubuntu 18.04LTS doesn't have "Before"